How to make a ComboBox pop-up next to a DataGridViewCell when editing that cell
I was wondering whether is possible to make a ComboBox pop-up next to a DataGridViewCell whenever editing it, this way I could choose from a list of records from my database.
Then of course whenever choosing a ComboBox item it would appear in the Cell I was editing.
I tried to make my DataGridView columns manually like this:
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colCategory = new();
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colCategoryId = new();
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colComponentId = new();
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colPartNumber = new();
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colDescription = new();
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colPackage = new();
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colManufacturerId = new();
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colLifecycleId = new();
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboColManufacturer = new();
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboColLifecycle = new();

dgProducts.AutoGenerateColumns = false;


colCategory.HeaderText = "category";
colCategoryId.HeaderText = "category_id";
colComponentId.HeaderText = "component_id";
colPartNumber.HeaderText = "part_number";
colDescription.HeaderText = "description";
colPackage.HeaderText = "package";
colManufacturerId.HeaderText = "manufacturer_id";
colLifecycleId.HeaderText = "lifecycle_id";
comboColManufacturer.HeaderText = "manufacturer";
comboColLifecycle.HeaderText = "lifecycle";
colCategory.DataPropertyName = "category";
colCategoryId.DataPropertyName = "category_id";
colComponentId.DataPropertyName = "component_id";
colPartNumber.DataPropertyName = "part_number";
colDescription.DataPropertyName = "description";
colPackage.DataPropertyName = "package";
colManufacturerId.DataPropertyName = "manufacturer_id";
colLifecycleId.DataPropertyName = "lifecycle_id";
comboColManufacturer.DataPropertyName = "manufacturer";
comboColLifecycle.DataPropertyName = "lifecycle";




Then after I populated the DataGridView with specific columns I tried to add data to it through an SQL query ordering all elements in the same order as the DataGridView columns are ordered:
string query = @"SELECT 
                    cat.name AS category,
                    cat.id AS category_id,
                    cpmf.component_id,
                    comp.part_number,
                    comp.description,
                    comp.package,
                    cpmf.manufacturer_id,
                    comp.lifecycle_status_id AS lifecycle_id,
                    man.name AS manufacturer,
                    lfs.name AS lifecycle
                    FROM components AS comp
                    INNER JOIN component_manufacturers AS cpmf ON comp.id = cpmf.component_id
                    INNER JOIN manufacturers AS man ON cpmf.manufacturer_id = man.id
                    INNER JOIN lifecycle_status AS lfs ON comp.lifecycle_status_id = lfs.id
                    INNER JOIN categories AS cat ON comp.category_id = cat.id
                    WHERE 1";

dgProducts.DataSource = Functions.MakeQuery(query);
comboColManufacturer.DataSource = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("manufacturer")).ToList();
comboColLifecycle.DataSource = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("lifecycle")).ToList();

//Populate data grids
dgProducts.Columns.AddRange(colCategory, colCategoryId, colComponentId, colPartNumber, colDescription, colPackage, colManufacturerId, colLifecycleId, comboColManufacturer, comboColLifecycle);

Edit: I added a DataSource to the columns, using the same select query above. This worked.
Now I have another problem, whenever selecting a row, it won't select the full row including the ComboBoxes, causing me an error since I made it do something on RowEnter. How can I automatically select the row whenever clicking the ComboBox?

There is a specialized kind of cell for comboboxes in DataGridView model. See DataGridViewComboBoxCell

Thanks, I'll see if my goal can be reached this way

I used your advice, can you review my edited post?

If you look carefully at the (incomplete) example in the link posted, you will notice that the DataGridViewComboboxColumn has its own datasource with proper ValueMember and DysplayMember set

You must use a separate sql query to get data from the database and fill the combobox with it.

All right, I tried using the DataSource of the ComboBoxColumn columns, it worked, but how can I do it separately from the other TextBoxColumn columns? These don't have a DataSource, so whenever I add them to my DataGridView they result being empty. Perhaps I should make a query only for the TextBoxColumn cells and 2 separate queries for each ComboBoxColumn cell?

Do not write in the comments. Edit the question. Show us the new code.

I edited, this way worked out for me but I have another issue, see at the end of the edit.
